# wget --content-disposition using python

Tags: python, cmd, wget

I am trying to download something from a website using python. I have some code in windows `cmd` from a batch file that works using

```
wget --content-disposition "url"
```

I want to be able to do this in a python script. How can I do this? So far I have

```
for name,ID in stations[stationid==26887]:
count=0
for y in year:
    for m in month:
        url = "http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID="+str(ID)+"&Year="+str(y)+"&Month="+str(m)+"&Day=14&timeframe=1&submit= Download+Data"
        print(url)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, str(count)+".csv")
        count=count+1
```

I get an **error** `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`. I assume this has something to do with not having the `--content-disposition` argument. Is there such an argument in the python wget module that matches what is being done in `cmd`? If I just copy and paste the url into the web browser it immediately begins to download a .csv file with its own unique name. Not sure why this isn't working through python. Here is what I get when I print my url:
    http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=26887&Year=2018&Month=8&Day=14&timeframe=1&submit=Download+Data

Answer (score 2):

Try using `urllib.request`.

```
import urllib.request
url = '<your url>'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'file.ext')
```

Now your file should be in your python's current working directory.

You can find your current working directory like this:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
# 'C:\\Python' would similar to the output if you are on windows
```

If you want to just have a `download` function that defaults the filename to the name of the downloaded file you can define this function like this.

```
def download(url, filename=url.split('/')[-1]):
    return urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
# This should download a file into your current working directory
download(url)
```

Comment: Is it possible to not provide a filename (file.ext) and to use whatever the filename is being downloaded from the website? I am doing this for a ton of files

Comment: I like this answer but I am still getting the Bad Request error that is why I was wondering if it had something to do with --content-disposition that the working cmd batch file has. is there some other argument I need to pass urlretrieve that is similar to this argument of cmd's wget?

Comment: I have edited my question above with a snip of my code.

Comment: I would like to see how the `url` looks when you print it. I tried the same url, `'http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=1&Year=2018&Month=3&Day=14&timeframe=1&submit=%20Download+Data' and it works fine.

Comment: I added what the url looks like when I print it. Maybe there is a problem with the space before Download Data? I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

python wget is not wget at all

from their docs they state

> wget.py is not option compatible with Unix wget utility,
>   to make command line interface intuitive for new people.

@nanomosfet has a good answer

If you are set on using wget you could use the subprocess module to call the real wget